# Watson iOS SDK (Swift) and passing context variable to Conversation

Tags: ios, json, swift, watson-conversation

I am attempting to pass a context variable at the start of a conversation from my iOS Swift application to the Watson Conversation service.  So far I have figured out you have to import RestKit to create the JSON object required and use the Context initializer.  Below is a sample of the code I have to start the conversation (I have included the try! for  brevity):

func startWatsonConv(){

```
    var cvar = JSON(json: ["shotInfo":"Pneumovax"])

    context = try! Context(json: cvar)

    let failure = { (error: Error) in print(error) }
    conversation.message(withWorkspace: conWorkspace, failure: failure) { response in
        self.context = response.context
        print ("start of conversation", response.context)
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error in the console:

fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: RestKit.JSON.Error.keyNotFound("conversation_id"): file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-800.0.63/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift, line 178

Any example of how to successfully pass this context variable would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would first send a first empty request to conversation service - you'll get back the response JSON with `context` with generated `conversation_id`. Then you just take this and add you desired var to the now populated `context` field.